# Raycast not detected when it should

Tags: c#, vector, unity-game-engine, detection, raycasting

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with me code ?
If you can see, whenever the player is in range of the raycast. The enemy turns red.
But for some reason. Even when the player has meet the requirement to make the enemy turn red. It turns back to white. This is only visible when you move it manually, in normal speed it looks as if it is flashing.

I believe a reason for this is happening is that, one of the raycast doesnt meet the requirement anymore. Probably something related to that. I dont know exactly. So please help me to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

This picture shows that even when the player is within the requirement of of making the enemy red. It doesnt. Why ?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

/* TL = Top Left
 * TR = Top Right
 * BL = Bottom Left
 * BR = Bottom Right
 */

public class Script_v2 : MonoBehaviour {

    // Player Properties
    private GameObject player;
    public Vector3 playerSize;
    private Vector3 playerTransform;
    public Vector3 playerTransformTL;
    public Vector3 playerTransformTR;
    public Vector3 playerTransformBL;
    public Vector3 playerTransformBR;

    private Vector3 newPlayerTransformTL;
    private Vector3 newPlayerTransformTR;

    private Vector3[] playerRaycastPoints;


    // Enemy Properties
    private Vector3 enemyTransformTL;
    private Vector3 enemyTransformTR;
    private Vector3 enemyTransformBL;
    private Vector3 enemyTransformBR;

    public float distance;
    public Vector3 enemySize;

    // Detection Alerts
    public bool alerted;
    public bool alertedLock;
    public bool dead;

    Ray ray;
    RaycastHit hit;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        playerRaycastPoints = new Vector3[4];

        distance = 3f;
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Player");


    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        enemyTransformTL = new Vector3 (transform.position.x - 0.5f, transform.position.y + 0.5f, transform.position.z);
        enemyTransformTR = new Vector3 (transform.position.x + 0.5f, transform.position.y + 0.5f, transform.position.z);


        enemyTransform_TL_TR ();
        detectionAlert ();
        Reference_Player_Transform_Points ();
        Player_Transform_Points_Detection ();



    }

    void OnDrawGizmos() {
        Gizmos.color = Color.blue;
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere (new Vector3(transform.position.x - 0.5f, transform.position.y + 0.5f, transform.position.z), distance);
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere (new Vector3(transform.position.x + 0.5f, transform.position.y + 0.5f, transform.position.z), distance);
    }

    public void enemyTransform_TL_TR() {

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

            double enemyAngleTL = Mathf.Atan2(playerRaycastPoints[i].y - ( transform.position.y + 0.5f ),
                                              playerRaycastPoints[i].x - ( transform.position.x - 0.5f )) * 180f / 3.14159265f;
            Debug.Log (enemyAngleTL);
            double enemyAngleTR = Mathf.Atan2 (playerRaycastPoints[i].y - (transform.position.y + 0.5f),
                                               playerRaycastPoints[i].x - (transform.position.x + 0.5f)) * 180f / 3.14159265f;

            Vector3 directionTL = (playerRaycastPoints[i] - enemyTransformTL).normalized;
            Ray rayTL = new Ray(enemyTransformTL, directionTL);
            RaycastHit hitTL;
            Vector3 directionTR = (playerRaycastPoints[i] - enemyTransformTR).normalized;
            Ray rayTR = new Ray (enemyTransformTR, directionTR);
            RaycastHit hitTR;


            //Debug.DrawRay (rayTR.origin, rayTR.direction * distance, Color.yellow);

            if(Physics.Raycast (rayTL, out hitTL, distance)) {
                if((enemyAngleTL > 90 && enemyAngleTL < 180)) {
                    Debug.DrawRay (rayTL.origin, rayTL.direction * distance, Color.yellow);
                    alerted = true;

                }

            }
            else {
                alerted = false;
            }


        }


    }

    public void detectionAlert() {
        if (alerted == true) {
            gameObject.renderer.material.color = Color.red;     
        }
        else {
            gameObject.renderer.material.color = Color.white;
        }
    }

    private void Reference_Player_Transform_Points() {

        playerSize = player.transform.localScale;

        playerTransformTL = new Vector3(player.transform.position.x - (playerSize.x / 2),
                                        player.transform.position.y + playerSize.y  / 2,
                                        player.transform.position.z);
        playerTransformTR = new Vector3(player.transform.position.x + (playerSize.x / 2),
                                        player.transform.position.y + playerSize.y  / 2,
                                        player.transform.position.z);
        playerTransformBL = new Vector3(player.transform.position.x - (playerSize.x / 2),
                                        player.transform.position.y - playerSize.y  / 2,
                                        player.transform.position.z);
        playerTransformBR = new Vector3(player.transform.position.x + (playerSize.x / 2),
                                        player.transform.position.y - playerSize.y  / 2,
                                        player.transform.position.z);

        playerRaycastPoints [0] = playerTransformTL;
        playerRaycastPoints [1] = playerTransformTR;
        playerRaycastPoints [2] = playerTransformBL;
        playerRaycastPoints [3] = playerTransformBR;

    }



}
```

Comment: part of your script is missing, namely the Player_Transform_Points_Detection() method...

Answer (score 0):

I didn't thoroughly read the whole thing but I smell something fishy, here goes: your state (color) depends on the "alerted" boolean, which is only ever affected in enemyTransform_TL_TR().

There you're casting through the 4 vertices of the player box (in 2D right?), **in a for loop** (that's the smelly part).

So if one cast succeeds it will turn alerted on, but if the next one in the for fails, then it will turn alerted off. Maybe you ought to turn alerted off before the for loop, then at the first cast that succeeds turn it on and break the for?

Also, I don't like the look of that cast, you're not handling one of the cases (see my "else" comment):

```
   if (Physics.Raycast(rayTL, out hitTL, distance))
   {
      if ((enemyAngleTL > 90 && enemyAngleTL < 180))
      {
         Debug.DrawRay(rayTL.origin, rayTL.direction * distance, Color.yellow);
         alerted = true;
      }
      // else: what then? should alerted be false? here's you're just leaving it as is...
   }
   else
   {
      alerted = false;
   }
```

Other than that, as I said in the comment your script didn't compile out of the box, the method `Player_Transform_Points_Detection()` is missing.

And, your code could use some cleanup: lots of unused variables, methods and variables made public for not apparent reason.

You should cache stuff more: like in `Reference_Player_Transform_Points()`, you're doing `player.transform.position` 12 times! which is effectively pulling the position from the engine each time. Just pull it once `var playerPos = player.transform.position;`, then use `playerPos` everywhere. Same for `playerRaycastPoints[i]` all over the place. Your code will be faster AND much more readable.

You're also dividing playerSize by 2 4 times, you could do it once (and multiply by 0.5f instead because divisions are costly, but that nitpicking and it could be that the compiler would do it for you anyway, I'm not sure).

You could use `Mathf.Rad2Deg` instead of `180f / 3.14159265f`, or at least `Mathf.PI`.

You can initialize fields inline: `private Vector3[] playerRaycastPoints = new Vector3[4];` directly instead of initializing on Start().

... OK I'll stop now ;) !

Comment: Thanks man ! I really appreciated what you said.
Thanks so much ! Haha, but umm, i solved this problem of placing, alerted = true; outside the for loop.
And as for the missing function. I forgot to remove that in the update cause i removed the entire function cause it wasnt necessary anymore.
If you could can you please help in me for:
http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/90368/problems-with-raycasting-requirements/90460#90460

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to accept the answer if it helped. I'll see if I can check out the other question tomorrow.